Burp Suite Out-of-scope Configuration Error
wanted to check if anyone know how we can configure the out-of -scope URL prefixes? im getting "Query parameters are not permitted for excluded URLs." but i would like to exclude Burp Suite Enterprise to not scan particular projects like abc.com/project_id=123 and abc.com/project_id=456. Are there any other walkarounds that we can do with this?
